# Magento 2 how to select/fetch data from database?

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I have created my custom module which posts data from magento to an API. How do I fetch the customer, category and order data from the Magento2 database? Will object manager help as a replacement for the `Mage::getModel()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**For Product data select/fetch:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getCollection();
/** Apply filters here */

$productCollection
->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
->addAttributeToSelect('name');
```

**For Category data select/fetch:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->getCollection();
/** Apply filters here */

$categoryCollection
->addAttributeToSelect('name');
```

**For Order data select/fetch:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();

/** Apply filters here */

$orderCollection
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Create resource model instance :-

Contoller file display.php in `contoller/forntend/Index/display.php`

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $postCollection = $objectManager->create('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Blog')->getCollection();
            $postCollection->addFieldToFilter(
                    array('title', 'content', 'name'),
                    array(
                        array('like' => "%$string%"),
                        array('like' => "%$string%"),
                        array('like' => "%$string%")
                      )
                  );
              $postCollection->setOrder('id', 'DESC');

              echo $postCollection->getSelect();
              $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
              $result->setData($postCollection);
```

using this your select data must be print ....
thank u.......